# Url parametrs are not sending Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

today is my first day when I've introduced with Guzzle and I'm trying to send a parameter to a website but it's not sending.Then I decided to find out the problem and created a simple script that prints my get request.

```
echo $_GET['locationId'];
```

And here I'm sending the request

```
require "./vendor/autoload.php";
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client([
    "base_uri" => "http://avto.com/",
    "version" => "1.1",
    "headers" => [
        'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
        'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
        'accept-encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
        'Host' => 'www.avito.ru',
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
        'Accept' => '*/*',
        'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'
    ]
]);

$response = $client->request("GET","test.php",[
    "form_params" => [
        "locationId" => "650370"
    ],
]);

echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

But it seems that my parameter doesnt send at all just because of my bad knowledge, what are you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form_params` is used for sending parameters for POST requests. Use `query` option instead, which is for GET requests. Read documentation here: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#query

Comment: Goddamn thank you so much you've solved my problem!